# How can I mount a non-AI lens on a Nikon F4?

Tags: nikon, film, lens-mount, old-lenses, vintage

I can't figure out how I am supposed to mount a non-AI lens on a Nikon F4.

I have read the [instructions on MIR](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonf4/compatibility/index.htm), but I can't figure out what they mean exactly.

> Remember to lift the meter coupling tab upwards (anyway, you won't be able to mount a Non-Ai lense onto the camera without lifting the tab), se the mode selector to "M" (manual focus);

What's the meter coupling tab? Is it the ring on the camera that spins together with the aperture ring on the lens. Is it something else? If it's the ring I don't see how I can "lift" it.

On [another site](https://www.photo.net/discuss/threads/stop-down-metering-protocol-nikon-f4-non-ai-lenses.489625/), it says:

> mount by lifting tab on mounting ring

What tab, and how to lift it? I am sure this is ultra-basic stuff, but I seem to be lost.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out!

Yes, the meter coupling tab is the tab on the ring on the camera that spins together with the aperture ring on the lens. In order to lift it, you first need to press inward the small prong near the white dot. When you press this prong, the coupling tab becomes loose and you can lift it. After that, you depress the prong and the tab will stay in place, and the non-AI lens will mount.

There's a [diagram here](https://www.photo.net/discuss/threads/nikon-f3-with-non-ai-lenses.474956/).

Answer (score 2):

Although you figured out the answer, I'd like to offer a suggestion.

While the F4 body can accept non-AI lenses, using them is not that convenient.  You have to do your metering in stop-down mode.

It is still possible to modify most non-AI lenses to be AI lenses in function.  There are a few web services available (look for John White if you are in the U.S., e.g.; he is a long-time AI modifier, and there are other shops that can do the job in the US and in other countries).  An aperture ridge will be milled, allowing your lens to connect to the AI coupling tab.  In some cases, if you are lucky, you can find the original Nikon AI-conversion aperture ring which will make your lens, effectively, an AI lens.  (There are some subtle differences between modified and real AI lenses, but they are very very minor.  John White's site explains the differences:  http://www.aiconversions.com/ .)

Have fun!  The F4 is a great body.